# Spark SQL command not working with doubles

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This returns data:

```
var cleanDF = readingsDF.filter(readingsDF("STR") > -1)
```

This returns no data:

```
var cleanDF = spark.sql("select * from readingsDF where STR > -1")
```

Both statements should be equivalent.

Here is the schema:

```
readingsDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- STR: double (nullable = true)
 |-- OBS: double (nullable = true)
 |-- AGMT: double (nullable = true)
 |-- FNDX: double (nullable = true)
 |-- HIGD: double (nullable = true)
 |-- DEG: double (nullable = true)
 |-- CHK: double (nullable = true)
 |-- AGP1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- AGMN: double (nullable = true)
 |-- NLV: double (nullable = true)
 |-- LIV: double (nullable = true)
 |-- WT: double (nullable = true)
 |-- AGLP: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MST: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How do you check _"This returns data:"_ and the other SQL query does not?

Comment: When you say _"Spark SQL command not working with doubles"_, what's the error?

Comment: Well now I ran this and it works: val cleanDF = spark.sql("select * from readingsDF where STR > -1").  So this issue should be closed as I must have left something out.  (But then again if I had done that there should have been some error.)

Answer (score 1):

Register a temp `table` before you perform a `SQL` query

```
readingsDF.registerTempTable("readingsDF") //for older version

readingsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("readingsDF")
```

than perform `SQL` queries

```
var cleanDF = spark.sql("select * from readingsDF where STR > -1")
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Both statements **could** be equivalent, but are **not** in general.

The two names are in different scopes and may refer to the same datasets, but may not too.

`readingsDF` after `val readingsDF` is a value in Scala. I *guess* it's a `DataFrame`. It could point to a dataset in a CSV file as follows:

```
val readingsDF = spark.read.csv("dataset.csv")
```

`readingsDF` in `select * from readingsDF where STR > -1` is a table or view registered in a catalog of relational entities in your Spark SQL application. It could be anything (including the Scala value above, but doesn't have to).

You could have the following in your code:

```
readingsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("readingsDF")
```

and only then you could say that the two `readingsDF`s point to the same dataset.

You could also have something as follows and they would not point to the same dataset.

```
spark.range(5).createOrReplaceTempView("readingsDF")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call the `Dataset.createGlobalTempView` method, the difference between this solution and @Shankar's one is the following :

Documentation of `Dataset.createGlobalTempView` says :

> Creates a global temporary view using the given name. The lifetime of this temporary view is tied to this Spark application.
>
> Global temporary view is cross-session. Its lifetime is the lifetime of the Spark application, i.e. it will be automatically dropped when the application terminates. It's tied to a system preserved database _global_temp, and we must use the qualified name to refer a global temp view, e.g. SELECT * FROM _global_temp.view1.

Instead of the `Dataset.createOrReplaceTempView` method :

> Creates a local temporary view using the given name. The lifetime of this temporary view is tied to the SparkSession that was used to create this Dataset.

So the solution will be something like that :

```
readingsDF.createGlobalTempView("readingsDF")
var cleanDF = spark.sql("select * from _global_temp.readingsDF where STR > -1")
```